# Unable to export RDS snapshot to S3: The Principal export.rds.amazonaws.com isn't allowed to assume the IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I have this error when I'm trying to upload an RDS snapshot to the S3 (in the same region), although I have the correct IAM role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "export.rds.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Error message:

```
Your request to export snapshot to S3 has failed.
The Principal export.rds.amazonaws.com isn't allowed to assume the IAM 
role arn:aws:iam::030578524176:role/service-role/rds-export-role or 
the IAM role arn:aws:iam::030578524176:role/service-role/rds-export- 
role doesn't exist.
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the role and/or your bucket?

Comment: Please include the error text in your question instead of linking a screenshot.

Comment: @Marcin, `AmazonS3FullAccess`

Answer (score 13):

Hi please add below in trust relationship of IAM role which you are using

"Service": "export.rds.amazonaws.com"

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-export-snapshot/

Comment: Thanks! Added below...
       
 {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "export.rds.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }

Answer (score 2):

I went around and around on this and kept getting the same error message. After trying all combinations of policy trust permissions, I finally hit the "refresh button" in the role selection area of the export page and then tried to export the snapshot again ... it worked! Crazy that you have to click refresh on the role even though the role is already there and just to get updated trust settings, but there it is. It's a very frustrating UI and hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: You're right. After adding 'export.rds.amazonaws.com' to the allowed assumed roles, I just refreshed the list, swapped the roles a couple of times to reload the role in question, and then it just worked. Thanks.